# Laravel URL expiration

Tags: laravel

I am creating a nanny booking system. 24 hours after booking I am sending an email to the parent user to review the nanny. I would like to send an url to the parent user so that when he clicks it, he can review the nanny. Everything else works besides the URL.  The url has to expire lets say with in 24 hours. I know I have to pass the token in the url but how should I go with the database design for that? And how can I expire the URL based on the token?

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Have a token table with a `created_at` date and check if the `created_at` is less than 24 hours ago when someone tries to access the page... is one of many many ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say you have a Booking Table, which would need at least the following fields

```
ID, user_id, nanny_id, created_at
```

or something similar, where `user_id` is the "parent user", and the `nanny_id` refers to the Nanny that was booked.
In such a case, the `created_at` field can be used to determine when a booking was made.
You can send a specific link to the parent including the booking_id

```
Route::get('/review/{booking_id}', ['uses' => 'BookingController@review', 'as' => 'booking.review']);
```

and then within the controller, you would simply:

```
public function review($booking_id)
{
    $booking = Booking::find($booking_id);
    if (Carbon::now()->greaterThan($booking->created_at->addDay())) {
        // the booking is more than 24 hours ago
        return "sorry you cannot review anymore.";
    }
    return "Please review the Nanny";
}
```

That way you wouldn't need an extra table with tokens etc.
Of course, if you need more flexible links, it might make sense to have an extra table just for specific actions that can have different expiration times.

Answer (score 1):

I think passing the token in some URL is a good solution. You can create a Model (and also a table) for the token where you specify the creation date, the expiration date and the status of the token. If the expiration date has expired then the URL is not usable anymore.

Hope that this aproach helps you.